# How can I add a click event to a button and get it to call a function?

Tags: jquery

I used the following to create a modal window:

```
function openAdminModal(dObj, content) {
    var modal = $.modal({
        title: dObj.title,
        closeButton: true,
        content: content,
        width: false,
        resizeOnLoad: true,
        buttons: {
            'Submit': function (win) {
                submitHandler(dObj.$link, $('#main-form'), false);
            },
            'Close': function (win) {
                win.closeModal();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I am not sure this helps with the question but I am adding it just in case.

The modal it creates has the following:

```
<div id="modal" style="display: block;">
....
    <button type="button">Submit</button>
```

The button is not inside of a form and the code around the button can't be moved. What I would like to do is to use jQuery to add an event to this button so that when it is clicked the following function is fired.

```
submitHandler(dObj.$link, $('#main-form'), false);
```

Can someone explain to me how I can use jQuery to add the calling of the function to the click event of the button. One thing I am not sure of is HOW can I select that button as it has no ID. The only thing it has is text of "Submit". Can I use the value of the variable modal that's on line 2 of the first code when doing my search?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dGdAc/)**

```
$('button:contains("Submit")').click(function(){
  submitHandler(dObj.$link, $('#main-form'), false);
});​
```

Comment: Is there some way I can just check for the button inside the window that has the id=modal ?

Comment: D'oh, edited. I think Anne means this: `$('#modal button')` assuming it's the only button inside that div. Otherwise she needs to give the button an ID and select it with `$('#modalSubmit')` (or whatever the ID is).

Comment: I think @Anne want something $('#modal button:contains("Submit")') as asked  "button inside the window that has the id=modal"